# Reset geo location

Tags: ubuntu-touch, location

I am using the nexus 4 with ubuntu touch ota 11.

When i am starting the weather app, it suggests the weather for the actual location.

I have disabled the indicator for the location a couple of days ago.

Does the phone store the last location? 
And where can it be reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the previous location data is not cached and re-used if location detection is turned off.

What the Weather app does is use the location data to find a location to add to the list of locations in the weather app. The app stores the location added to it, and displays weather data for that location when detection is turned off. If you swipe up from the bottom, you'll see the list of locations, where you can add other locations you want to get weather data for.

Comment: I see that switching the in app config for not using location data to disabled resets the suggested location in the weather app.